# Binding Nested Object with MVC and Json

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

i am trying to post a JavaScript object to my MVC controller, however its not binding the nested object.

c# object:

```
    public class OrderHeader
    {

        public OrderHeader()
        {
            this.orderAddress = new OrderAddress();
        }

        public int SubTotal{ get; set; }
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }


        public OrderAddress orderAddress;



    }




public class OrderAddress
    {

        public OrderAddress()
        {
        }

        public int id { get; set; }

        public int OrderID { get; set; }

        public string BillToFName { get; set; }


  }
```

js object:

```
{ OrderNumber: "KM123", SubTotal: "10", orderAddress: { BillToFName: "street 2" } }
```

I can read orderNumber and SubTotal perfectly fine within my controler, however BillToFName is NOT binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a getter and setter to your property:

```
public OrderAddress orderAddress { get; set; }
```

Comment: you sir just saved me alot of time.